# How do I make a div fill the remaining screen space and internal divs with same height?

Tags: html, css

I have created the following webpage.

CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -44px; /* -44px being the size of the footer */
}

#header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

#headerPlace
{
    width: 990px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ddd;
}

#content
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-1
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: -1px; /* Thank you IE */
    width: 190px;
    background: #bfb;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
}

.content-2
{
    float: right;
    width: 800px;
    background: Aqua;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
}

#footer, #push
{
    height: 44px;
}
#push
{
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: Aqua;
}

.content-1-push
{
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    background: #bfb;
    position: absolute;
}

.content-2-push
{
    float: right;
    width: 800px;
    background: Aqua;
    position: absolute;
}
#footer
{
    width: 100%;
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

a img
{
    border: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerPlace">
                <a href="Default.aspx">
                    <img src="siteImages/logo.jpg" class="logo" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-1">
                content-1
            </div>
            <div class="content-2">
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2
                content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="push">
            <div class="content-1-push">
            </div>
            <div class="content-2-push">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        footer</div>
</body>
```

However, I want the content-1 section to be the same height as that of content-2; that is that background color will not display below content-1, as shown in the attached image.

[image: css styling; browser display]

Comment: what you is your question ?

Comment: I need that the push part will look like the content part. for that i add two div in the push div, but it doesn't look like the content. I need help with fixing it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrPzC/). It should set you on the right path.

To briefly explain, you want to set the `min-height: 100%;` for the `.content` class to ensure that it will stretch to the either the maximum height the content takes up, or that of the page. Then you give your `content-2` `div` an `absolute` position and set the left margin to the width of `content-1`.

Comment: The height of the content works perfectly, the problem is with the filling of the push